# Examples of past tense/future tense of "Forgo"

Tags: verbs

Exactly what the title says, I was just wondering what the past and future tenses of the word "forgo" are and how they would be used in a sentence.

Example: "He chose to forgo his music career to focus on his education."

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forgo: "third-person singular simple present *forgoes*, present participle *forgoing*, simple past *forwent*, past participle *forgone*". Future tense, for those who like to call it thus, is left as an exercise to the reader. And in "He chose to forgo" that's an infinitive anyway, so it doesn't change. The main verb is *choose*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Compact Oxford English Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/forgo?q=forgo) suggests that it is conjugated like *to go*

> verb (forgoes /-ˈgəʊz/, forgoing, forwent /-ˈwɛnt/; past participle forgone /-ˈgɒn/)

Comment: Strictly speaking this is true, but *"By choice, he **forwent** his music career to focus on his education."* would probably be seen as somewhat "quirky" by many/most people (who wouldn't see anything at all odd if I'd used *"gave up"* there instead).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Once, when I asked a waiter in rural Ireland if he had any local wine, he said, "Ah, we have it, but you don't want it." Just because it can be conjugated, doesn't mean it should be. I am forsworn to avoid *forwent*.

Comment: I was going to forbear from quoting OED, but *Pa. tense -bore (-ˈbɔə(r)), pa. pple. -borne (-ˈbɔən). Forms: see for prefix1 and bear v.; in pa. tense also rarely 5 forbored, 6 -beared,* (so it turns out I haven't forborne/forbored/forbeared at all! :)